# What should I add in order to iterate the loop to print as "1->2->3->"?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to print a linked list with data type struct node ("not the traditional way i.e. struct node *). To get to the next node what should i add in the while loop?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
int main()
{
    struct node first;
    struct node second;
    struct node third;
    first.data = 1;
    first.next = &second;
    second.data = 2;
    second.next = &third;
    third.data = 3;
    third.next = NULL;
    struct node ptr;
    ptr = first;
    while(ptr.next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr.data<<" ";
                  //WHAT SHOULD I ADD?????
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copying the pointer copy the object it is pointing by dereferencing it (`*(ptr.next)`).

```
while(1)
{
    cout<<ptr.data<<" ";

    if (ptr.next)
       ptr = *(ptr.next);
    else 
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confused between iterating with a *pointer* or attempting to iterate with type `struct node`. You must use a pointer:

```
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = &first;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
            //WHAT SHOULD I ADD?????
            ptr = ptr->next;
    }
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_fixed_nodes
1 2 3
```

**Using a Pointer to Iterate Over nodes**

The following diagram may help you understand why using a pointer makes sense for iterating over your nodes. Each block below represents a `struct node` where the `next` pointer holds the address for the next node:

```
    +--------+      +--------+      +--------+
    | first  |  +-->| second |  +-->| third  |
    |   data |  |   |   data |  |   |   data |
    |   next |--+   |   next |--+   |   next |-->NULL
    +--------+      +--------+      +--------+
```

First iteraion, `ptr` points to (holds the address of) `first` as its value:

```
ptr = &first;
...                 // 1 is output
ptr = ptr->next;    // ptr now points to second
```

Second iteration:

```
...                 // 2 is output
ptr = ptr->next;    // ptr now points to third
```

Third iteration:

```
...                 // 3 is output
ptr = ptr->next;    // ptr now points to NULL and loop exits
```